# How to retrieve a list of included client libs from a component in CQ?

Tags: java, jstl, aem

Is it possible to determine, what client libs have been loaded prior to a component?

We are running multiple site backed by different Javascript frameworks. In order to run a single component across the board, it's not sufficient to just use
`<cq:includeClientLib categories="blah"/>`
We need to identify the respective framework (i.e. AngularJS, Vanilla, jQuery, blah) in order to facilitate the integration.

We are looking for a decent server side solution.

Comment: Please Refer this link : http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/clientlibs-explained-example/ . "blah" name should be meaningful as it will point towards your particular js framework.

Comment: Hey yeah, I know, but the thing is. I'm not trying to load in any client libs. I just want to know what client libs have already be loaded (namely by the template containing the component) so the component can intelligently render/integrate with the site.

Comment: May be this can be helpful : http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.test.html Here just mention the category and you will know about whats is getting load.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually done this, but it would presumably be *possible* if you are buffering your output to clone the JspWriter buffer or examine it to see what it already contains.  That sounds ugly to me, though.  But this is decompiled code for how the cq:includeClientLib tag adds libraries to the output, which may show you how you can read back what was previously written:

```
package com.adobe.granite.ui.tags;

import com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.scripting.SlingBindings;
import org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.util.TagUtil;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class IncludeClientLibraryTag extends TagSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3068291967085012331L;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IncludeClientLibraryTag.class);
    private String categories;
    private String js;
    private String css;
    private String theme;
    private Boolean themed;

    public IncludeClientLibraryTag() {
    }

    public void setPageContext(PageContext pageContext) {
        super.setPageContext(pageContext);
        this.categories = null;
        this.js = null;
        this.css = null;
        this.theme = null;
        this.themed = null;
    }

    public void setCategories(String categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public void setJs(String js) {
        this.js = js;
    }

    public void setCss(String css) {
        this.css = css;
    }

    public void setTheme(String theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
    }

    public void setThemed(boolean themed) {
        this.themed = Boolean.valueOf(themed);
    }

    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        SlingHttpServletRequest request = TagUtil.getRequest(this.pageContext);
        HtmlLibraryManager libManager = this.getHtmlLibraryManager(request);
        if(libManager == null) {
            log.warn("<ui:includeClientLib>: Could not retrieve HtmlLibraryManager service, skipping inclusion.");
            return 6;
        } else {
            JspWriter out = this.pageContext.getOut();

            try {
                if(this.categories != null) {
                    libManager.writeIncludes(request, out, toArray(this.categories));
                } else if(this.theme != null) {
                    libManager.writeThemeInclude(request, out, toArray(this.theme));
                } else if(this.js != null) {
                    if(this.themed != null) {
                        libManager.writeJsInclude(request, out, this.themed.booleanValue(), toArray(this.js));
                    } else {
                        libManager.writeJsInclude(request, out, toArray(this.js));
                    }
                } else if(this.css != null) {
                    if(this.themed != null) {
                        libManager.writeCssInclude(request, out, this.themed.booleanValue(), toArray(this.css));
                    } else {
                        libManager.writeCssInclude(request, out, toArray(this.css));
                    }
                }

                return 6;
            } catch (IOException var6) {
                String libs = this.categories != null?"categories: " + this.categories:(this.theme != null?"theme: " + this.theme:(this.js != null?"js: " + this.js:(this.css != null?"css: " + this.css:"")));
                throw new JspException("Could not include client library: " + libs, var6);
            }
        }
    }

    private HtmlLibraryManager getHtmlLibraryManager(ServletRequest request) {
        SlingBindings bindings = (SlingBindings)request.getAttribute(SlingBindings.class.getName());
        return (HtmlLibraryManager)bindings.getSling().getService(HtmlLibraryManager.class);
    }

    private static String[] toArray(String commaSeparatedList) {
        if(commaSeparatedList == null) {
            return new String[0];
        } else {
            String[] split = commaSeparatedList.split(",");

            for(int i = 0; i < split.length; ++i) {
                split[i] = split[i].trim();
            }

            return split;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the best solution may be to use the [**client library**](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/clientlibs.html) dependencies or embed attributes in your library, though, or let the client-side JavaScript test if a library is present (ex. test if the jQuery object is undefined) and then take appropriate action.  In other words, let the client side determine the final rendering based on what libraries exist on in the client.  It sounds like this may not be possible for your situation, though.

> **dependencies**: This is a list of other client library categories on
>   which this library folder depends. For example, given two
>   cq:ClientLibraryFolder nodes F and G, if a file in F requires another
>   file in G in order to function properly, then at least one of the
>   categories of G should be among the dependencies of F.
>   **embed**: Used to > embed code from other libraries. If node F embeds nodes G and H, the
>   resulting HTML will be a concetration of content from nodes G and H.